# Simulate button effect with CSS background-image?

Tags: html, css

I was looking for some ways of putting kinda-custom buttons on site, using my own images.

And than I found out some interesting moment on Formspring site. There is just one image file, with all states of button - hover and pushing.

[image: Like this]
<sub>(source: [formspring.me](http://cdn.formspring.me/images/global/social-fsvaf743e61c7e51b26765c392c6ee597f7994ad03f.png))</sub>

And this image is on background. I wonder - is it possible with CSS - changing part of background image you show on hover and pushing?

May be you can provide example of how that could be done?

Comment: Just Google "CSS sprite".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/eAp2H/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the `background-position` when the different states are triggered.

```
div{
    background:url('http://cdn.formspring.me/images/global/social-fsvaf743e61c7e51b26765c392c6ee597f7994ad03f.png');
    width:191px;
    height:29px;
}

div:hover{
    background-position-y:-29px;
}
```

Check my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ApJR9/

Answer (score 0):

```
button { background: url(../images/bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent; }
button:hover { background-position: 0 20px; }
button:active { background-position: 0 40px; }
```

Browser catches different events, like mouseover (:hover), or click (:active), and you can set the style for each of those events.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
#facebook{background:url('img_navsprites_hover.gif') 0 0;}
#facebook:hover{background: url('img_navsprites_hover.gif') 0 -45px;}
```